# moment.js compare two australian timezones

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Can anyone please assist?
I have my times below format. first is the date field and the second one is the current date
14/12/2020 7:13 AM
14/12/2020 9:13:45 AM

I want to compare if the first date(time) is before the current time. this can also go the next day. Basically, I want is the comparison of the first time is  less than the current time.

I am using moment `isBefore()` but having issues as the time the function requires time in UTC. I am not aware how to convert the time in UTC

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:momentjs] so why not use it? [Parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) the dates then use [`isBefore()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)